# Apply different boosting values when searching for phrase in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, boost, term-query

I want to search for a phrase to Elasticsearch like "personal tax date". I want the returned results to give more weight to the term "tax".

So far I know how to boost entire index or boost for different fields but still don't know how to boost different terms? Any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **function score** we can boost by fields

```
GET <index_name>/_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
           "query": {
            "query_string": {
               "query": "*personal tax date*",
               "fields": [
                "field_1",
                "field_2"
               ]
            }
            },
            "boost": "5",
               "functions": [
                          {
                  "filter": { "match": { "field": "tax" } },
                  "weight": 30
              },
              {
                  "filter": { "term": { "ent_name": "tax" } },
                  "weight": 25
              }
          ],
             "score_mode": "multiply",
            "boost_mode": "sum"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `query_string` query and boost the term using [query string syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boosting) as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "personal tax^2 date"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how can I multiply a term's importance by a floating number?

Comment: `tax^2` here the boost value can be any floating value. Or use function score to modify the score calculated by elastic